# Is the ouput of a given LDO high impedance when the LDO is shutdown

Tags: voltage-regulator, impedance, ldo

If a LDO is in shutdown, is the output of the LDO high or low impedance? Specifically for the [LT3065.](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt3065.pdf)

Comment: *Probably high impedance*- Since the pass element has to be off, and there's no active discharge, there's probably only a small amount of leakage current drawn by the output in the off state.  (At least as long as Vout isn't pulled above Vin.)  But to be sure you'd have to contact ADI or run some experiments yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that it would be high impedance since it has built in reverse protection.

> The LT3065 withstands reverse voltages on the IN pin with respect to
> its GND and OUT pins. In such case, such as a battery plugged in
> backwards, the LT3065 behaves as if a diode is in series with its
> input. No reverse current flows into the LT3065 and no reverse voltage
> appears at the load. The device protects itself and the load.
> Source: LT3065  Datasheet